# Crash on newer android version

Tags: java, android

I had done an app. Work nicely in emulator Nexus 5x API26 x86. 
However it crash run in some other android version
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.myessentialoils.reprogramyourmind

Crash 1
LGE V20 (elsa), 4096MB RAM, Android 7.0

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:    at java.util.Random.nextInt
>   (Random.java:391)   at
>   tk.myessentialoils.reprogramyourmind.MyService$TimeDisplayTimerTask$1.run
>   (MyService.java:92)

Can anyone go through my java classes and show me how to optimize them?

```
    private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
            //this is the line 92 crash, randomStr
                public void run() {
                    String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];

                    final Toast Notify = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),randomStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView toastMessage = (TextView) Notify.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    toastMessage.setTextSize(21);
                    Notify.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    Notify.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    Notify.show();

                    Handler cancelToast = new Handler();
                    cancelToast.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Notify.cancel();
                        }
                    }, DISPLAYTIME);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: probably array length is 0 for some reason.

Comment: please give information about array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)]; line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the comment.
That's my thinking too. Most probably the array.length is 0 or not being passed.

So my solution will be to implement a check, if length = 0 then break the code.